# Display saved text onclick in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very, very new to `React.js` and javascript in general(I'm more of a C# programmer). I encountered this issue with my node application and it's driving me insane!

Basically I wanted to create a textarea that when a button is clicked it displays the text in another area (for this testing purpose render that text in h1 tags below the button).

I managed to get as far as storing the text from the textarea and triggering a bool to true when you click the button... but it wont display the  text.
My logic thought process this was that whatever is written into the text area is saved, but only when the button is clicked and the bool is true will it display elsewhere on the application or in this case the h1 tags.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    
    this.state =
        {
          emailField:  [],
          buttonPushed: false
        };
  }

  handleChange = (e) =>
    {
        this.setState({emailField: e.target.value});
    }
    
    buttonPushedHandler = () =>
    {
        this.setState({buttonPushed:true});
    }
    
     displayText = () =>
    {
        if(this.state.buttonPushed)
        {
            return (
                <h1>{this.state.email}</h1>
            )
        }
    }
    
    
  render()
      {
          return (
              <div className='App'>
                  <h4>Create your post below:</h4>
                  <textarea className='text-saver' onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  <br/>
                  <button onClick={this.buttonPushedHandler}>Display Post</button>
    
                  <br/><br/><br/>
                  
                  {this.displayText}
              </div>
          )
      }
  }
    
    export default App;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional rendering to show the text of the textarea.

Try the below code.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state =
            {
                emailField: '',
                buttonPushed: false
            };
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ emailField: e.target.value });
    }

    buttonPushedHandler = () => {
        this.setState({ buttonPushed: true });
    }

    render() {
        let emailStats = null;
        if (this.state.buttonPushed) {
            emailStats = (<h1>{this.state.emailField}</h1>);
        }
        
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                <h4>Create your post below:</h4>
                <textarea className='text-saver' onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <br />
                <button onClick={this.buttonPushedHandler}>Display Post</button>

                <br /><br /><br />

                {emailStats}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root">
        loading.....
    </div>
```

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. I thought I replied a very long time ago. This fixed the issue I had back then, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the React community! I'll post a hooks version in case that interests you or anyone else.

Firstly, let's create a separate component for the h1. This will replace the emailStats variable.

```
function EmailStats({ email }) {
  return <h1>{email}</h1>;
}
```

This returns whatever we pass in as the email prop (I've done some destructuring here to avoid the props.email syntax).

Now let's create the parent component. I've called it "HookVersion" for clarity. First we set the state with the useState hook. **Email** and **buttonPushed** are currently set to "" (empty string) and false.

This mirrors your state of **emailField** and **buttonPush**

```
function HookVersion() {
   const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
   const [buttonPushed, setButtonPushed] = useState(false);
   // ...We'll see the rest soon
}
```

Next we set up the handleChange function to run when the user types in the textarea. Inside it we call our **setEmail** hook to set the value of e.target.value to our email variable.

Up to now, all of the logic is the same but with hooks.

```
function HookVersion() {
    //...
    function handleChange(e) {
        const { value } = e.target; // more destructoring...it reads clearer to me
        setEmail(value);
    }
    //...more to come
}
```

Next we render the HTML with a *conditional* component **EmailStats** (the component we made earlier).  We pass in *email* and **only** render if *buttonPushed* is true. This conditional rendering is because JavaScript has this handy conditional && operator which will only return the component **if** the previous value is true.

```
function HookVersion() {
      //... all of the state
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h4>Create your post below:</h4>
          <textarea className="text-saver" onChange={handleChange} />
          <br />
          <button onClick={setButtonPushed(true)}>Display Post</button>

          <br />
          <br />
          <br />

          {buttonPushed && <EmailStats email={email} />}
        </div>
      );
}
```

Here's the full version for clarity.

```
function HookVersion() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [buttonPushed, setButtonPushed] = useState(false);
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setEmail(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Create your post below:</h4>
      <textarea className="text-saver" onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={setButtonPushed(true)}>Display Post</button>

      <br />
      <br />
      <br />

      {buttonPushed && <EmailStats email={email} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function EmailStats({ email }) {
  return <h1>{email}</h1>;
}
```